# LightBox conflict with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I'm using a lightbox inside a jQuery reload page as you can see here:

http://www.ermes.net/adsearch/listdocument_theme.php?form=viaggio

The problem is when I reload the page using jQuery the lightbox is stop to work. I think that is a conflict between javascript library.

And I'm using a fancybox

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fancybox01").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
        'width'         : 700,
        'height'        : 400,
        'overlayColor'  : '#000',
        'overlayOpacity': 0.8,
        'type'          : 'iframe'
    });
 });
```

Comment: Where in your link is jquery/lightbox used?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this can be a $ conflict. Sometimes, libraries uses prototype and other jquery. This can result to a conflict.

Here is an article on how to avoid this : 
http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 0):

not sure try this:

```
jQuery.noConfilt();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("#fancybox01").fancybox({..
```